# How can i searching in TabActivity for each activity in tab

Tags: java, android, search, tabactivity

When i don't have tab. It can show data ok
But when i add tab, Then i search. It can not show data

Can you give me some example

Answer (score 0):

May be the reason, your searching result not fit into the particular tab. Did you do through ActivityGroup?